# What is a fair way to assign authorship?

Tags: discussion

Given the fact that [Academia.SE](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/16617/academia) still is in the commitment phase, I'm asking this on a individual basis.  Hopefully it will be relevant (and interesting) enough to ask here.

What is the way in which normally, when working in collaboration with other people, it is decided the authorship for a research paper?. Obviously, it varies widely, but it would be nice to know.

What is a fairer way to decide authorship or how would you like it to be decided? (In case you regard as the current standard way in your field, not so fair).

Comment: this certainly does not belong on meta.phsyics.se. I haven't just migrated it because I want to mention that it looks like a combined poll (*how would **you** like...*) and  Big List to me (there are dozens of schemes for doing this), and I'm not sure it is a good fit for physics.SE; can I convince you to try your luck on the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71)?

Comment: @dmckee: Of course, I will try in the chat. By the way, I know it doesn't fit in Physics.SE, that's why I give it a try here (in the hope it could be relevant). Could you migrate it to the chat or how does that work?.

Comment: chat doesn't have "questions" as such, but if you enter a line that is only a link to a Stack Exchange question it will be partially rendered inline, which is probably suitable.

Comment: @dmckee: Alright, done. Hopefully I will get some answers. Fingers crossed. Thanks for your help.

Comment: (3 comments up): just remember that meta is for questions about the physics site itself.